# woocommerce remove_action not working but add does

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I have added the following code to the bottom of my functions.php file and they are not removing the functions from my product page.  I copied the priority numbers directly from the content-single-product.php page and still no luck!

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5  );
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 10 );
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price',10  );
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt',20  );
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart',30 );
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta',40 );
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_sharing' ,50);
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data()',60 );e
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to include them in a custom function hooked in `woocommerce_single_product_summary` action hook with a smaller priority this way:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'customizing_single_product_summary_hooks', 2  );
function customizing_single_product_summary_hooks(){
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_title', 5  );
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_rating', 10 );
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_price',10  );
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_excerpt',20  );
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart',30 );
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_meta',40 );
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_sharing' ,50);
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data()',60 );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

This way it should work

Comment: Nice answer! technically, the smallest priority would be `PHP_INT_MIN`, but that's just being technical! :)